# How can I set up a dedicated screen area for an application in Python?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

A good example is MS OneNote. It has the option to be fixed to one side of the screen and pushes all other windows to the side. When maximizing or resizing other windows, they can only expand up to the edge of OneNote. Does Python have this capability using Tkinter or another module? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: [Not a complete answer, but...](http://eviacam.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=eviacam/eviacam;a=blob_plain;f=wxutil/wxappbar.cpp;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The win32 feature you're looking for is called [Application Desktop Toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx) - it allows your application to cooperate with the shell and reserve space along the side, similar to the taskbar.

If you want to implement this yourself, you'll likely need to use Win32 somehow.

It looks like there's a python wrapper for this, however: searching for python and appbar turned up [wxAppBar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxAppBar) which seems to be a python wrapper for it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to figure out how to install and import win32 but thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I'll update this post once I get it working. easy_install wxAppBar is not working for me either (error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('wxAppBar')).

Answer (score 1):

See the Microsoft documentation on ["Windows"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and ["Window Features"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This being windows-specific stuff, the only way to set these properties is using the Win32 API or similar.

The `pywin32` module exposes the Win32 API to Python. There's even a [pywin32](/questions/tagged/pywin32) tag!

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has very little control over the behavior of the rest of the windows on the OS. There's no built-in cross-platform function for this.