# Python application for windows that uses Application Desktop Toolbars

Tags: python, wxpython

I am building an application that displays information, Currently its functionality has been tested to work in tkinter however I have not found where I can work tkinter in to reserving space on the screen for it to stay persistent without getting in the way of the user. after some brief research I found what I am attempting to do is use the [Application Desktop Toolbars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx) features in windows. I have found that there is [wxAppBar](https://pypi.org/project/wxAppBar/) from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371916/how-can-i-set-up-a-dedicated-screen-area-for-an-application-in-python/9375993#9375993). However I do not have enough experience with wx to figure out how to call for it. Can i get some help creating a basic bar?

Comment: `Latest version, Feb 28, 2004`, I doubt the toolbar is still usable.

Comment: Then is there any current modules (tkinter, wx, or otherwise) that support creating a desktop toolbar?

Comment: I have no clue, just wanted to point it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wx.ToolBar still works!
https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started

Johnf

Comment: I will have to rebuild my GUI pages but thanks for the info!